# Which late-nineties TV show had a woman fighting for the safety of an alien man she loved?

Tags: story-identification, tv, aliens

In 1997 (give or take few years), there was this TV show about a man who was from some other planet and this brown-haired woman who fell in love with the man and fought for his safety.

I don't remember any more. I've tried to Google TV shows like this but I haven't found it yet. I remember what the woman looked like if I ever came across a picture, but nothing more.

Comment: I'm afraid there are many stories that fit this description. Isn't there anything else you remember it for?

Comment: describing what you do remember about the characters might go a long way.

Comment: @Catzy: What country was the show from? America? Did the guy have any special powers? What was the woman's job? Who was she keeping him safe from? Can you remember any examples of events that happened in the show?

Comment: I remember both "Starman" and "Mork and Mindy" in the United States, however, both pre-date this question.

Comment: Were the two characters you mention the only main characters? Roswell has a larger main cast (including more aliens), but otherwise fits the (rather vague) description including the time period.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a great deal like [*Roswell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roswell_%28TV_series%29).  [Shiri Appleby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiri_Appleby) played the female lead that would match your description.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like "Starman", the movie from 1984 and the TV show from 1986, but they aren't in the timeframe you mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the timeframe, I can only think of *[The Visitor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118509/)*, starring John Corbett. It came out in 1998.

Comment: Wikipedia and IMDB don't mention a female love interest as described in the question. Was there one?

Comment: @phantom42 I vaguely recall the protagonist having left behind family, including a woman.  This was touched on a few times during the series.